# Set length property of JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a JavaScript object:

```
function a(){
    var A = [];
    this.length = function(){
        return A.length;
    };
    this.add = function(x){
        A.push(x);
    };
    this.remove = function(){
        return A.pop();
    };
};
```

I can use it like so:

```
var x = new a();
x.add(3);
x.add(4);
alert(x.length()); // 2
alert(x.remove()); // 4
alert(x.length()); // 1
```

I was trying to make `.length` not a function, so I could access it like this: `x.length`, but I've had no luck in getting this to work.

I tried this, but it outputs `0`, because that's the length of `A` at the time:

```
function a(){
    var A = [];
    this.length = A.length;
    //rest of the function...
};
```

I also tried this, and it also outputs `0`:

```
function a(){
    var A = [];
    this.length = function(){
        return A.length;
    }();
    //rest of the function...
};
```

How do I get `x.length` to output the correct length of the array inside in the object?

Comment: Here's some interesting reading about [attempting to subclass Array](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you call `a.length`, you're returning a function. In order to return the output you have to actually invoke the function, i.e.: `a.length()`.

As an aside, if you don't want to have the length property be a function but the actual value, you will need to modify your object to return the property.

```
function a() {
  var A = [];
  this.length = 0;
  this.add = function(x) {
    A.push(x);
    this.length = A.length;
  };
  this.remove = function() {
    var removed = A.pop();
    this.length = A.length;
    return removed;
  };
};
```

Comment: This is a valid answer, except that you've modified the return value of the `.remove()` method (not by any design flaw in your answer, though).

Comment: @JAAulde Thanks I must've added that when I was writing my own. Updated to be similar to Rocket's original question.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`valueOf` hack](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript):

```
this.length = {
    'valueOf': function (){
        return A.length;
    },
    'toString': function (){
        return A.length;
    }
};
```

Now you can access the length as `x.length`. (Although, maybe it's just me, but to me, something about this method feels very roundabout, and it's easy enough to go with a sturdier solution and, for example, update the length property after every modification.)

Comment: faster than me and best answer...+1!

Comment: That's a pretty hacky way of doing it.  I like it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want `A` to stay 'private', you need to update the public `length` property on every operation which modifies `A`'s length so that you don't need a method which checks when asked. I would do so via 'private' method.

**Code:**

```
var a = function(){
    var instance, A, updateLength;

    instance = this;
    A = [];
    this.length = 0;

    updateLength = function()
    {
      instance.length = A.length;
    }

    this.add = function(x){
        A.push(x);
        updateLength();
    };

    this.remove = function(){
        var popped = A.pop();
        updateLength();

        return popped;
    };
};
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/VT4bb/

Answer (score 1):

While what everyone has said is true about ES3, that length must be a function (otherwise it's value will remain static, unless you hack it to be otherwise), you can have what you want in ES5 (try this in chrome for example):

```
function a(){
    var A = [],
        newA = {
         get length(){ return A.length;}
        };
    newA.add = function(x){
        A.push(x);
    };
    newA.remove = function(){
        return A.pop();
    };
    return newA;
}

var x = a();
x.add(3);
x.add(4);
alert(x.length); // 2
alert(x.remove()); // 4
alert(x.length); // 1
```

You should probably use `Object.create` instead of the function a, although I've left it as a function to look like your original.

Comment: Cool, this works (in Chrome 13).  Didn't know about the `get length()` syntax.

Comment: It works in a lot of browsers: Chrome 12, FF4. Not yet implemented in IE though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access it as a variable as a variable to my knoledge cannot return the value of a method, unless you will hijack the array object and start hacking in an update of your variable when the push/pop methods are called (ugly!). In order to make your method version work I think you should do the following:

```
function a(){
    this.A = [];
    this.length = function(){
        return this.A.length;
    };
    this.add = function(x){
        this.A.push(x);
    };
    this.remove = function(){
        return this.A.pop();
    };
};
```

Comment: My current, 'method', version works fine.  `A` did not have `this.` in front of it, because that makes it a 'private' member of the function.

Comment: ah, my bad. I missed the var. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

These days you can **use defineProperty**:

```
let x = {}

Object.defineProperty(x, 'length', {
  get() {
    return Object.keys(this).length
  },
})

x.length // 0
x.foo = 'bar'
x.length // 1
```

Or in your specific case:

```
Object.defineProperty(x, 'length', {
  get() {
    return A.length
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function a(){
    this.A = [];
    this.length = function(){
        return this.A.length;
    };
    this.add = function(x){
        this.A.push(x);
    };
    this.remove = function(){
        return this.A.pop();
    };
};
```